# Order Statistics Expected Value

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, order-statistics

Can someone help me with this question? I have arrived with the distribution function equal to $g(y) = \frac{n}{\theta }\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta }\right)^{n-1}$. But couldn't solve the integral for the expected value, and I don't know if I did it right. please help. The problem I am having is I am not sure how to integrate $E(y) = \int y\frac{n}{\theta }\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta }\right)^{n-1}$

[image]

Comment: Have you tried substituting $u = 1-\frac{y}{\theta}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let $x=\frac{y}{\theta}$ so your integral simplifies to
$$
\theta\int_0^1xn(1-x)^{n-1}dx.
$$
Now, let $u(x)=x$ and $v(x)=-(1-x)^n$, then integration by parts yields
$$
\theta\int_0^1xn(1-x)^{n-1}dx=\theta\int_0^1 u v'=\theta\left(uv|_0^1-\int_0^1 u'v\right)\\
=\theta\left([-x(1-x)^n]|_0^1+\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx\right)=\theta\left(0+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{\theta}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: This integration is correct, the answer isn't. $E(Y_{(1)})=\frac{1}{n+1}$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Order_statistics. You have built an extra $\theta$ in at some point.

Comment: @ Dale M: $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is for uniform $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try integration by parts.